# FLUTTER: How to add last seen functionality in list view builder

Tags: flutter

I am creating a book and different chapters in listviewbuilder. Each Chapter has there own explanations and in that a lot of items in that chapter so my problem is how the user can save/bookmark/last read option in that explanation if the user will close the app and open it again there will be a bookmarks option in which they go to read the last where they left...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's very simple,
Make it like master[chapter] page and detail[Explanation] page
just store the chapter/explanation information in local storage using **shared_preferenceS** or some other way,

when you go to detail [Explanation] page, store the page info in local storage, update it every time you got to new page[Explanation],

Use **Router** to route the use to detail page(store in local storage) whenever user open up the APP.